# Aggregating data with SQL if other values in rows meet certain criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot

I'm pretty new to SQL and am trying to figure out if there's a way to aggregate the date into new column. For instance, below is a sample set of date. I want to take all the type '2' and create new columns

```
Mem   Balance  Type  New
 1     2500     2    0
 2     722      66   1
 3     9422      1   0
 4     122       2   1
 5     788      66   1
```

So instead of having it like above, it would be like

```
Mem   Type2Balance  Type66Balance   Type2New    Type66New
1       2622            0            1             0
2         0            1510          0             2
```

Is there a way to do this in SQL? I thought maybe using IF statements within a case statement? I'm not asking for it to be done for me, more of looking for specifics that I can read about to make this happen. Thank you!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want:

```
select
    case when type = 2 then sum(balance) else 0 end type2balance,
    case when type = 66 then sum(balance) else 0 end type66balance,
    case when type = 2 then sum(new) else 0 end type2new,
    case when type = 66 then sum(new) else 0 end type66new
from mytable
where type in (2, 66)
group by type
```

I am not sure what logic you want for column `Mem` in the resulset. It that's just a row number, then:

```
select
    row_number() over(order by type) mem,
    case when type = 2 then sum(balance) else 0 end type2balance,
    case when type = 66 then sum(balance) else 0 end type66balance,
    case when type = 2 then sum(new) else 0 end type2new,
    case when type = 66 then sum(new) else 0 end type66new
from mytable
where type in (2, 66)
group by type
```

We could put the conditional expression on `type` inside the aggregate function, but it does not really make sense since you are grouping by `type` already. In that case, that would be:

```
select
    row_number() over(order by type) mem,
    sum(case when type = 2 then balance else 0 end) type2balance,
    sum(case when type = 66 then balance else 0 end) type66balance,
    sum(case when type = 2 then new else 0 end) type2new,
    sum(case when type = 66 then new else 0 end) type66new
from mytable
where type in (2, 66)
group by type
```

Comment: You're right about Mem column. Each entry has a member number. I won't be needing it for this project, so I can remove it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select min(mem) mem,
  sum(case when type = 2 then balance else 0 end) Type2Balance,
  sum(case when type = 66 then balance else 0 end) Type66Balance,
  sum(case when type = 2 then new else 0 end) Type2New,
  sum(case when type = 66 then new else 0 end) Type66New
from tablename
where type in (2, 66)
group by type
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kJ4KDnTATct4ePy6YgATho/0).
Results:

```
| mem | Type2Balance | Type66Balance | Type2New | Type66New |
| --- | ------------ | ------------- | -------- | --------- |
| 1   | 2622         | 0             | 1        | 0         |
| 2   | 0            | 1510          | 0        | 2         |
```